# Xen boots old kernel after upgrading

Tags: grub2, xen

I've upgraded linux kernel from 3.2.0 to 3.16.3. Now Xen boots the old one (3.2.0) instead of 3.16.3. Is there any way to force Xen to find that a newer linux kernel version is available? Or am I stuck with 3.2.0 kernel?

**EDIT**: I've updated dom0 kernel. I don't need to boot domU with that kernel (domU is Windows), but instead boot new kernel of dom0 (with Xen available).

Answer (score 2):

Xen usually starts a kernel that lives outside of the DomU; look in your DomU config file in `/etc/xen`, there should be a `kernel` option that specifies which kernel your DomU is using. Upgrading the kernel *inside* the DomU therefore doesn't have any effect because Xen doesn't know about this kernel.

You should either:

a) copy the new kernel somewhere to the Dom0, and then update your DomU configuration file to use this new kernel. Note that you have to keep the kernel file on the Dom0 in sync with the kernel modules that live in the DomU.

or

b) set up [PyGrub](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/PyGrub) so that Xen is able to boot kernels that are installed inside your DomU. This is the solution I'd recommend because it's much more elegant than keeping the kernel separately on the Dom0. From then on, the DomU will behave normally and always use the kernel that you have installed inside of it.

Comment: Sorry it my question is not clear. I've completely forgot to mention, that I've updated dom0 kernel and want to boot that new kernel. My domU is Windows. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Hmm, that should usually work without any manual changes. What distro are you using, and how did you update the kernel? Did you use distro packages, or did you compile the kernel by hand? Check your `grub.cfg`, that decides which kernel should be booted, but usually your distro should take care of this automatically.

Comment: I've compiled the kernel by hand. I'll check grub.cfg, thanks.